# What type of code is `gameplay` in my code and how does it function?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I know this is a strange request, but I don't completely understand why my code works from a syntactical standpoint. to be clear, it does work as intended, an is entirely my own code, but I'm a little lost about what I did to get to where I am. Each individual function withing the `gameplay' object (or function, I don't know what it is called) can be ignored.

```
const Player = function(name, symbol, score) {
  return {name, symbol, score};
}
let playerOne = new Player(document.getElementById('oneName').value, 'x', 0);
let playerTwo = new Player(document.getElementById('twoName').value, 'o', 0);
 const updateNames = function() {
  playerOne.name = document.getElementById('oneName').value;
  playerTwo.name = document.getElementById('twoName').value;
}
const gameplay = (() => {
  let turn = 'x';
  const board = {
    1: '',
    2: '',
    3: '',
    4: '',
    5: '',
    6: '',
    7: '',
    8: '',
    9: ''
  }
  const checkWinner = function() {
    let winCombinations = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [3, 6, 9],
      [1, 5, 9],
     [7, 5, 3],
    ];
    winCombinations.forEach(function(array) {
      let x = 0;
      Object.keys(board).forEach(function(key) {
        if (board[key]) {
          x += 1;
        }
      })
      if (board[array[0]] === 'x' && board[array[1]] === 'x' && board[array[2]] === 'x') {
        displayWinner(playerOne.name ? playerOne.name : 'Player One');
        playerOne.score += 1;
        document.getElementById('oneScore').innerHTML = playerOne.score;
      } else if (board[array[0]] === 'o' && board[array[1]] === 'o' && board[array[2]] === 'o') {
        displayWinner(playerTwo.name ? playerTwo.name : 'Player Two');
        playerTwo.score += 1;
        document.getElementById('twoScore').innerHTML = playerTwo.score;
      } else if (x === 9) {
        displayWinner(false);
      };
    })
  }
  const displayWinner = function(winner) {
    const x = document.getElementById('winMessage');
    x.innerHTML = winner ? `${winner} is the winner!` : 'TIE!';
    x.style.display = 'flex';
    x.addEventListener('click', refresh);
  }
  const refresh = function() {
    updateNames();
    const x = document.getElementById('htmlBoard');
    while (x.firstChild) {
      x.removeChild(x.lastChild)
    }
   for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      board[i] = '';
    };
    document.getElementById('winMessage').style.display = 'none';
    turn = 'x';
    render();
  }
  const restart = function() {
    playerOne.score = 0;
    playerTwo.score = 0;
    document.getElementById('oneScore').innerHTML = playerOne.score;
    document.getElementById('twoScore').innerHTML = playerTwo.score;
    const x = document.getElementById('htmlBoard');
    refresh();
    turn = 'x';
  }
  const commitPlay = function() {
    if (!(board[event.target.id])) {
      if (turn === 'x') {
        event.target.className = 'x';
        event.target.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
        board[event.target.id] = 'x';
        turn = 'o';
      } else {
        event.target.className = 'o';
        event.target.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
        board[event.target.id] = 'o';
        turn = 'x';
      }
      checkWinner();
    }
  }
  const render = function() {
    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      let tile = document.createElement('div');
      tile.id = i;
      document.getElementById('htmlBoard').appendChild(tile);
      tile.addEventListener('click', commitPlay);
    }
  }
  return {board, render, restart, refresh};
})(); //<----

document.getElementById('clearBoard').addEventListener('click', gameplay.refresh);
document.getElementById('newGame').addEventListener('click', gameplay.restart);
window.onload = function () {
  gameplay.render();
};
```

The main question I have is about the `gameplay` object/function. What is it, and how does that impact how my code works? Additionally, I have added an arrow to the closing line of it because I don't understand why I need the open and close parenthesis on the same line with nothing inside for it to work, but without them it doesn't work.

Since this is such a weird question and phrased horrendously, I will be monitoring this question closely to clarify anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an IIFE (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) just with an arrow function instead of a "regular" `function`

Comment: Opening and closing the parenthesis calls the function you defined immediately ('invoke'). Everything that is inside that function is no longer accessible by anyone outside the function except that which was returned by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the pieces (with some abstraction).

```
() => {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

What is this? It's just a function, but it's completely anonymous in that you haven't named it and it can't be called by name. It's essentially equivalent to:

```
var someFunc = function() {
    console.log("foo");
}
```

Except that in this latter example, you now have a handle to call the anonymous function via the `someFunc` variable.

You could do the same with the anonymous function defined by the arrow syntax if you desire. But that's not what you've done in your example code. Instead you have something like this:

```
const gameplay = (() => {
    // stuff happens in here
})();
```

You point out that you're confused about what this does and how it works.

Essentially, you have an anonymous arrow function, wrapped in a pair of parantheses, with `()` at the end. Well, let's look at it another way, that would do the exact same thing...

```
const temporaryFunctionHandle = () => {
    // stuff happens in here
};
const gameplay = temporaryFunctionHandle();
```

This is essentially equivalent, except you have defined a variable to store the anonymous function. All that wrapping the anonymous function in parentheses and then putting another pair of parentheses `();` at the end does is call that function without storing it to a variable. The `const gameplay =` in front of it just assigns the `return` from that function call to the `gameplay` variable, which is why when the anonymous function returns an object with the shape `{board, render, restart, refresh}` you are then able to access those properties via `gameplay.board`, `gameplay.render` and so on.

Here's another way it could be written and perform essentially the same task:

```
function buildGameplayObject() {
    // do stuff
    return { board, render, restart, refresh};
}

const gameplay = buildGameplayObject();
```

As you can see, if you didn't include the `();` at the end of the `const gameplay = ...` line, you wouldn't be executing the `buildGameplayObject` function and assigning its return value to the `gameplay` variable, but instead you would just be assigning a reference to the `buildGameplayObject` function to the `gameplay` variable. You would then need to call `gameplay()` (or `buildGameplayObject()`) and assign the return to *another* variable to access the returned properties of the object.

This is what the `();` at the end of `const gameplay = (() => {}})();` is doing - it is explicitly calling the anonymous function that has been created and assigning the returned object to the `gameplay` variable.

**But *why?***

A common question when looking at this kind of syntax is... why do it this way? Well, simply the answer is that inside of the anonymous function you create a lot of variables, you declare a number of functions that you *do not need or want access to* directly, you just want access to those resulting properties (in this case, functions). It's similar to what you're doing with the `Player` function, except you only need the result of the anonymous function once, so you are safely discarding access to it once you have built the `gameplay` object.

Hopefully this helps to clarify your understanding of what is happening in your code.